# Amazon AWS S3 404 error on page refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Getting the error mentioned below when I try to refresh the react based application which I deployed in Amazon AWS S3.

Did anyone face the same issue recently?

`404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: <KEY>
RequestId: C8BE5E360A29AA14
HostId: <HOSTID>`

Comment: please check file permissions and see if file name is correct. just do a search for the error, there are lots of questions.

Comment: Hi @SudharsanSivasankaran.. Its a react application and no HTML files. Earlier I used to upload the zip file and it took care of everything but now something has changed or I am missing something...

Comment: It does not unzip the app for you, was there any automation? or were you using any other tools? Please update your question with S3 settings and how are you uploading the zip file.

Answer (score 26):

[image]

Fixed it :) ... I added index.html in error document section.

Comment: Thanks it helped me alot :)

Comment: Glad it helped :) Happy coding. You can mark it as correct answer if it worked :)

Comment: After trying this solution, I still get a 404 if I do a "hard refresh" (hold down Ctrl while refreshing). Does that happen for you?

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. But want to know what is the reason behind it.

Comment: @mnhmilu since the application is an SPA, when you are routed to it, it works fine due to the React Router. But when you hit refresh, it tries to hit the exact URL which does not exist. Hope that made sense.